# How to render pdf by phantomjs directly to Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, phantomjs

I'm asking if there is a way to render pdf files using PhantomJS directly into Amazon S3. I don't want to save those files on the server and then upload them to S3.

This code is saving files in a folder on my server.

```js
page.open('https://google.com', function(status) {
  console.log('opened page? ', status);
  page.paperSize = {
    format: 'A4'
  };
  page.render('pdf/google.pdf', function() {
    console.log('page rendered');
  });
});
```